# Fit Poisson distribution to normal distribution

Tags: matlab, image-processing, statistics, distribution, probability

I have a set of data. I plotted the histogram of these data in order to know their distribution, which gives me a Poisson distribution. I want to fit my data as Gaussian. Is it possible to fit the Poisson distribution to a Gaussian distribution under Matlab?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You can get good approximations of a Poisson distribution using a normal distribution but only when the mean of the Poisson is sufficiently large. You might want to look at this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Related_distributions

Comment: Thank you but in my case I have a very low values as my input which normally give a very low mean !!! -2.1643<Data<6.5198

Comment: Hmm but if you have negative values, then you can't really describe it as Poisson...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it concerns statistical modelling rather than programming.

Comment: Thank you again I think so really I'm confused about the fact that my data are poissonian or something else I don't know how can I be sure

Comment: Well if your data has negative or non-integer values then it will not follow a classical Poisson distribution. If you feel that your histogram has the look of a normal distribution then there are tests such as the Q-Q plot http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%E2%80%93Q_plot you can use to test the normality assumption.

Comment: I plotted the QQ plot by using qqplot function under matlab , I obtained the result in the added image, what do you think? for me I see that my data are too close to the normal distribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`normfit`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/normfit.html) to obtain the mean and standard deviation of a Gassian distribution fitted to your data, and then [`normpdf`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/normpdf.html) to generate the pdf.

Here's an example with invented data. The data in this case has a triangular-shaped distribution (not a Poisson ditribution), but the idea is the same: a Gaussian function is fitted to it.

See above link for `normfit` options.

```
%// Random data
data = sum(rand(2,1e4)); %// sum of two uniform RV's gives a triangular pdf

%// Plot normalized histogram (empirical pdf) of data
edges = 0:.1:2;
[yh xh] = hist(data, edges);
bar(xh, yh/numel(data)/(edges(2)-edges(1)))

%// Compute and plot Gaussian fit
[mu, sigma] = normfit(data);
hold on
xf = -1:.01:3;
plot(xf, normpdf(xf, mu, sigma), 'r');
```

[image]

Comment: I've applied the same code on my data and I obtained the attached histogram in my question I could not interpret the values around zero and two

Comment: Well, your histogram seems to have two spikes. If you use different data and the spikes are still there, that means the data is not Poisson